# Get Max Value per ID column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

In my query below, I am looking to get the MAX value of SEQNBR field per USERID, where that USERID does not have a row with the STATUS value of 'CLE'.

I am able to retrieve the MAX SEQNBR Row per USERID, however it is not excluding USERID's where they have a row in the table with the value "CLE".

Due to constraints in the environment where the query will ultimately run, I would like to avoid using Common Table Expressions (CTE) and subqueries in the SELECT clause.

```
SELECT A.USERID, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.TEST_DT,121))AS 'TEST_DATE', A.TYPE_CD, 
 (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.NEXT_TEST_DT,121))AS 'EXPIRE_DATE', B.STATUS1, 
 B.MGR_CLR, B.COMMENT, C.COMPANY, D.DESCR, E.DESCR, 
 F.LAST_NAME, F.FIRST_NAME, B.SEQNBR 
FROM ((((((TEST_PLACEMENT A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  TEST_STATUS B ON  B.USERID = A.USERID AND B.TEST_DT 
= A.TEST_DT ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (PS_JOB C INNER JOIN PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY C1 ON (C.USERID = 
C1.USERID AND C.EMPL_RCD = C1.EMPL_RCD )) ON  
C.USERID = A.USERID ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_JOBCODE_TBL D ON  D.JOBCODE = C.JOBCODE ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_DEPARTMENT_VW E ON  E.DEPTID = C.DEPTID ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (PS_JOB G INNER JOIN PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY G1 ON (G.USERID = 
 G1.USERID AND G.EMPL_RCD = G1.EMPL_RCD )) ON  
 G.POSITION_NBR = C.REPORTS_TO AND G.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX( H.EFFDT) 
 FROM PS_JOB H, PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY H1 
 WHERE H.USERID = H1.USERID 
 AND H.EMPL_RCD = H1.EMPL_RCD 
 AND ( G.POSITION_NBR = H.POSITION_NBR )) ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (PS_NAMES F INNER JOIN PS_PERALL_SEC_QRY F1 ON (F.USERID = 
F1.USERID )) ON  F.USERID = A.USERID ) 
WHERE ( ( 
 C.JOB_INDICATOR = 'P' 
 AND B.SEQNBR = 
  (SELECT MAX(BB.SEQNBR) FROM TEST_STATUS BB
   WHERE  BB.USERID = B.USERID AND BB.STATUS1 <> 'CLE')
   --GROUP BY BB.STATUS1)
 AND G.EFFSEQ = 
    (SELECT MAX(G_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_JOB G_ES 
    WHERE G.USERID = G_ES.USERID 
      AND G.EMPL_RCD = G_ES.EMPL_RCD 
      AND G.EFFDT = G_ES.EFFDT) )))
```

The code in question is:

```
  (AND B.SEQNBR = 
  (SELECT MAX(BB.SEQNBR) FROM TEST_STATUS BB
  WHERE  BB.USERID = B.USERID AND BB.STATUS1 <> 'CLE')
  --GROUP BY BB.STATUS1))
```

**This is sample data of what is in the main query now:**

[image]

**Here is what the desired results would look like (based on original sample above):**

[image]

As you can see, USERID's 1 and 3 have been eliminated, based on them each having a row with 'CLE' status, and the row for USERID 5 with SEQNBR 37 is removed because it is not the MAX SEQNBR for that USERID (SEQNBR 38 is for USERID 5).

Answer (score 1):

You need to test all rows

```
SELECT MAX(BB.SEQNBR) 
FROM TEST_STATUS BB
WHERE BB.USERID = B.USERID 
  and not exists (select 1 
                  from TEST_STATUS cc 
                  where ccUSERID = BB.USERID 
                  AND cc.STATUS1 = 'CLE')
```

Comment: This works great in SQL Manager and provides the expected results, however the tool I am looking to have this run from can not have the 2nd level sub-query in it. Any other thoughts for structuring it?

Comment: You can't run subqueries at all? Can you use temporary tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
And b.seqnbr=(Select max(bb.seqnbr) from     TEST_STATUS bb
Where bb.user_id not in (
Select t2.user_id from TEST_STATUS t2 where t2.status='CLE'
)
and bb.user_id=b.user_id
Group by bb.user_id)
```

Comment: Please, try to add explanations to your answer for others to understand how and why it works.